# Should req.user store all user information in Express application

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am working on setting up logins with session using Express, express-session, and passport.

In a passport documentation as I go I see this example: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/profile/

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Also, I was following this tutorial: https://github.com/bradtraversy/node_passport_login

Now according to these examples deserializeUser stores the user information in `req.user`. However, I see that the whole `user` is stored which puzzles me, as this also stores the passwords to the object.

Isn't that risky?
Or maybe it is not possible to access `req.user` from front end?

Comment: You can't access req.user from the frontend. Only if you pass it to the frontend.

Comment: So it is safe, to pass the user information (password, access rights to sections of webpage) in the req.user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your backend server is not compromised, `req.user` will stay only in your backend, which should be a trusted environment, and will not be sent back to your client via `res` by default.

Also, anything stored within `req` will only be available in the request itself, another request will have its own `req` instance, so data is not shared and should not leak to another request unless purposely made to do so.

However, you should always be staying on the ball, keep in mind to test and make sure all data sent back to your client does not have any sensitive info contained within them (e.g. password, tokens).

If you are not comfortable with storing that in `req.user`, you can always add a layer of middleware to strip the sensitive info before reaching your controller. This way, routes that use the middleware will not have sensitive info exposed.